# Facebook iframe does not go to top when new page loads

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

Hi i cannot for the life of me find a solution to this.. i have searched on ehre and tried every suggested solution for this issue...

nothing seems to work with a facebook/iframe combination

as this guy said 
Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as well as many other solutions I tried: onload="window.parent.scroll(0,0);", document.getElementById("someTopDivId").scrollIntoView();, $(window/html/body).scrollTop(0);... Nothing seems to work with the Facebook iframe combination :( – BBog Dec 8 '11 at 9:40

from here
[Scrolling to the top of a new opened page inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427742/scrolling-to-the-top-of-a-new-opened-page-inside-an-iframe)

problem is this
when user gets to bottom of page 1 (inside iframe) on facebook tab, and click "next page"
it then loads the page 2 into the iframe but in the same place eg at the bottom
and not the top 
forcing user to scroll back up to the top to conuntinue reading page 2

there are MANY simialr questions but cant seem to find a solution
anyone know how to beat this issue?

would have thought its a pretty big one as iframe is being used by many in this way on FB
surely someone has fifgured this out?

appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

just use FB JS SDK's FB.Canvas.ScrollTo.

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/ for more info.

Comment: thanks for chiming in
im usng one of the free iframe tab editors, to embed a URL
so im not sure i have access to use that?
sorry im a bit of a programming newb!

Comment: the FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); would only work if you created your own facebook app not one of those free iframe tab editors.

Comment: depends on the implementation, as long as your page is directly embeded into facebooks iframe it will work. (header redirect for example, have such a app for easy fangating too) - and then all FB.JS methods works... (...when they are working :D)